# Exchange 2010 not accepting Email traffic (not recognising domain name)

Tags: exchange-2010, hosted-exchange

Experiencing emails being bounced from Exch 2010, not recognising email address.  The following is the configuration:

- Exchange 2010 on 2008 Svr R2 64bit, also acting as HUB Transport.
- DC is 2008 R2 (AD) - local network domain is bordnagaidhlig.local.
- Email relayed from 3rd party using gaidhlig.org.uk as domain name.

This configuration is a new build with no migration from 2003 SBS.

We have changed domain hosting and prior to changeover all worked fine.  However MX records were deleted by previous host prior to new host accepting domain change.

Hub Transport (Server) is set to 2 receive connectors (194.105.xxx.x/25 and 194.105.xxx.x/25) with default authentication.  ISP can telnet to Exchange server Port 25 but mail throughput is bounced as email address not recognised.

Hub Transport (Client) is using smarthost - mailhost.xxx.co.uk, however we cannot telnet to host Port 25 and subsequently all traffic is being qued at Exch.

Port 25 has been configured for SMTP.

any help with this would be appreciated as it is now critical to business.

Regards,

Craig

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that under Organization Configuration>Hub Transport>Accepted domains, you have spelled your domain correctly and that it is Authoritative.

Here are the default settings for the Default Receive Connector on my server:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

The defaults for the For the Client Receive Connector are similar, but on the Authentication tab, uncheck "Exchange Server Authentication"; and on the Permission Groups tab, the only one checked is "Exchange Users".

Otherwise, it would be helpful to have the exact bounce message in its entirety.

Comment: Thanks for the concise and very explanatory answer, much appreciated.  This seems to have sorted one part of the problem as we can now send out from Exchange.

Comment: However one part of the equatio which I missed out which I 'thought' was not a part of the problem was that we also changed domain hosting at the same time.  The releasing host decided upon merit to delete MX records rather than wait for the receiving host to take over,  Propagation time (48 hours) falls this morning and I am hoping that this will then sort the problem, together with your explanation above.  I will add to this if this is either positive or negative.  I must say though that moving from 2003 Server to 2008 with Exchange 2010 is challenging to say the least, a lot has changed.

Comment: Back to the drawing board - current ISP has this morning telnet to Exchange and they are receiving a header response which would indicate that MX records are current and propagated.  When sending a test telnet email to the exchange they are receiving error 500 5.7.1, which my research has identified that the Exchange server has been 'told not to work with the sender (host)'.  Completely at a loss now, any help would be appreciated.